# Using developer tools on a Thuderbird add-on dialog

Tags: firefox-developer-tools, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I was having trouble getting Thunderbird's developer tools inspector to focus on an add-on's dialog box, since the usual technique of using the "pick an element" tool doesn't function there, nor do you get the "inspect element" option on right-click in the iframe. So, I thought I would post the solution here to help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use the "Select an iframe" button on the right side of the toolbar:
[image: Screenshot of Thunderbird developer tools showing the Select an iframe button]

This will show a long list of iframes, one of which should be your add-on's dialog in the format:

```
chrome://myaddon/content/myaddonDialog.xul
```

Unfortunately, you still have to dig around through the tree to find the right elements, but at least they are highlighted in red on the iframe while you are searching.